# Consume Service method in View-Model [WPF-MVVM]

Tags: wpf, mvvm, service, mef

Hi try port my Winform app to WPF with MVVM. I use Caliburn Micro and MEF as IoC. I have service in external dll -> **Pokec_Toolki.dll** and this services use other external dll such as JSON.NET, HtmlAgilityPack..etc (third party libraries).

My service look like this:

```
public interface IPokecConnection
{
    PokecAccount LogOn(string nick, string password);
    bool LogOff(PokecAccount account);
}

[Export(typeof(IPokecConnection))]
public class PokecConnection : IPokecConnection
{
}
```

For my Service I create consumer for class PokecConnection, it is in the same assembly as Service:

```
[Export]
public class PokecConnectionConsumer
{
    private readonly IPokecConnection _pokecConn;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public PokecConnectionConsumer(IPokecConnection pokecConn)
    {
        _pokecConn = pokecConn;
    }

    public PokecAccount MethodWrapperForLogOn(string name, string  password)
    {
        return _pokecConn.LogOn(name, password);
    }

}
```

I have simple view with 2 textbox  and 1 button. I bind event click of button with caliburn convention on view-model.

**View:**

```
<Button Micro:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action LogOn(tbNick.Text,tbPassword.Text)]"
        Content="Prihlás ma"
        Width="100" 
        Grid.Row="2"
        Height="25" Margin="4,4,4,4" />
```

I need consume service method in my view model.  So in view-model I have this:

```
[Export(typeof(IShellViewModel))]
public class ShellViewModel : Screen, IShellViewModel, IDataErrorInfo
{

    private PokecConnectionConsumer _connConsumer;

    protected override void OnInitialize()
    {
        base.OnInitialize();

        var mycatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("Pokec_Toolkit.dll"));

        var container = new CompositionContainer(mycatalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);

        _connConsumer = container.GetExportedValue<PokecConnectionConsumer>();
    }

    //this method is bind on event click of button in view
    public void LogOn(string nick, string password)
    {
        //call method LogOn from class PokecConnection in external dll through PokecConnectionConsumer

        var accout = _connConsumer.MethodWrapperForLogOn(nick, password);

        // in this place if account is not null, I need close this view and create new view MainView 
        //a send to the MainViewModel constructor as argument variable account

        //some test 
        MessageBox.Show(accout.SessionId);
    }


}
```

I have these question:

1. First, It is good create consumer
   for service class in external dll?
   In my case PokecConnectionConsumer
   **and this class is in  same assembly
   as service class PokecConnection?
2. It is correct way to load external
       assembly in view-model in method
       OnInitialize?
3. It is correct call service method in
       view-model?
4. It exist more suitable way how bind
       method from external dll on view
       control ? I need simple load external dll in wpf app with MVVM
   and bind service method on controls
   in views. What is the best way?

**How can I close actual view and create new view, also activate this view. I need send as argument variable from view-model to another vie-model constructor.****

**MY SOLUTION:**

I create interface assembly and refer this assembly in external service dll and also in wpf app.

In bootstraper I load this assembly with reflection:

```
    var catalog =
    new AggregateCatalog(
        AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>());

catalog.Catalogs.Add(
    new AssemblyCatalog(string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}", System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"\Pokec_Toolkit.dll")));

_container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
```

Than I create conductor class:

```
public interface IShellViewModel
{
    void ShowLogOnView();
    void ShowMessengerView();
}

[Export(typeof(IShellViewModel))]
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>, IShellViewModel
{
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        ShowLogOnView();
    }

    public void ShowLogOnView()
    {
        ActivateItem(IoC.Get<LogOnViewModel>());
    }

    public void ShowMessengerView()
    {
        ActivateItem(IoC.Get<MessengerViewModel>());
    }
}
```

And in view-model I have this:

```
  [Export]
    public class LogOnViewModel : Screen, IDataErrorInfo, ILogOnViewModel
    {

        [Import]
        private IShellViewModel _shellViewModel;

        [Import]
        private IPokecConnection _pokecConn;

//this method is bind on event click of button
        public void LogOn(string nick, string password)
        {
            //SHOW NEW WIEW
           _shellViewModel.ShowMessengerView();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, so that if the external dependency changes, you do not have to recompile your UI. Also it must be outside View/VM logic.

2) Not I am afraid. Create a separate service class for it.

3) Same, Create a separate service class for it and use within VM.

4) Well, you have to load a DLL anyway. So load it in the service class.

Comment: Hi Aliostad, thank for advance but I use another solution. My solution is on top.

Comment: So post an answer and make that the answer for the sake of others who are gonna read and learn.

Comment: My solotiun is under my question.

Comment: Yes but it is recommended that you post an answer and flag as the real answer.

Comment: Aaah, perhaps it is the limitation of the point, you soon will be able to.